# insurance grading policy sql iif statement

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2007

I would like to produce the following result:

```
Table:[0050 Fix No Hit].[Fix_No_Hit]
Policy Number:     Insurance Score:   Insurance Score Factor:
100                  500                     2.13
101                  720                     1.47
102                  815                     1.00
103                  900                     0.69
```

Using the rules below:

```
Table: Tier_InsuranceScore
Insurance Score Chart:                      Factor:                 
649 or below                           2.13
(i assume insurance score has to be greater than 0) 
650 to 699                             1.86
700 to 799                             1.47
800 to 849                             1.00
850 to 899                             0.82
900 or above                           0.69
```

This is what I have so far:

```
SELECT HWData.[Policy Number],
   [0050 Fix No Hit].[Fix_No_Hit],
   iif([0050 Fix No Hit].[Fix_No_Hit] <=649, 2.13, 0),
   iif([0050 Fix No Hit].[Fix_No_Hit] <=699, 1.86, 0),
   iif([0050 Fix No Hit].[Fix_No_Hit] <=799, 1.47, 0),
   iif([0050 Fix No Hit].[Fix_No_Hit] <=849, 1.00, 0),
   iif([0050 Fix No Hit].[Fix_No_Hit] <=899, 0.82, 0),
   iif([0050 Fix No Hit].[Fix_No_Hit] >=900, 0.69, 0)
FROM [0050 Fix No Hit];
```

Once again I am getting

```
    2.13 0 0 0 0 0 for policy 100
and 0 0 1.47 0 0 0 for policy 101
```

but I just want one column as the result.

Comment: Adam, I dont think its working, but I think you are close.

Comment: I won't receive a message notification if you do not comment on my answer, or include @adamwenger.  I found the issue, updating answer now.

Comment: Chen, the question about the negative values should probably have been a second question, instead of modifying your original question requesting help with your `iif()` statement.  This helps keep the questions/answers/comments you receive more on topic.

Comment: Thank you for moving your second question to it's own question.  I have reverted this question to it's original form, and removed the second part which you have a new question for now.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to nest your `iif()` statements:

```
SELECT HWData.[Policy Number],
   [0050 Fix No Hit].[Fix_No_Hit],
   iif([0050 Fix No Hit].[Fix_No_Hit] <= 649, 2.13, 
   iif([0050 Fix No Hit].[Fix_No_Hit] <= 699, 1.86, 
   iif([0050 Fix No Hit].[Fix_No_Hit] <= 799, 1.47, 
   iif([0050 Fix No Hit].[Fix_No_Hit] <= 849, 1.00, 
   iif([0050 Fix No Hit].[Fix_No_Hit] <= 899, 0.82, 
   iif([0050 Fix No Hit].[Fix_No_Hit] >= 900, 0.69, 0))))))
FROM [0050 Fix No Hit];
```